# How to pass arguments from inside a python to a remote ssh command in stdin, stdout, stderr

Tags: python, shell, paramiko

I am connecting to a remote host via SSH using `paramiko` and running some simple commands like `cd`. In the second command, i need to pass an argument as shown in the sample below:

```
import paramiko 
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import socket
X='ABCDF12'
p=paramiko.SSHClient()
p.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
p.connect("example.com",username="tatta",password="abcy1")
print(socket.gethostname())

stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command("cd /bca/scripts;touch $X") 
opt = stdout.readlines()
opt = "".join(opt)
print(opt)
```

Expected : `ABCDF12`
Actual : `touch command not working`

Comment: `touch command not working` -- is this the actual output? I don't find anything online about this message, so assuming not. Please upgrade your sample to a [mcve].

Comment: @laenkeio : ys its fake only...

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is in the `exec_command()` argument. Try this:

```py
stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command("sh -c 'cd /bca/scripts; touch {}'".format(X))
```

It runs the commands in a shell (so e.g. `cd` works), and the {} expands the X variable.

Comment: ..used your code...but getting error as below                                                           
    import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
./test1.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test1.py: line 7: `p=paramiko.SSHClient()'

Comment: If you're trying to run an X command and forward the screen through paramiko, I think you'd better open a new question with details on that.